# Check if foreach contains more than 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            int i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var group in ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.MissingDays).GroupBy(x => x.Month))
        {
           i++;
           var month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(group.Key);
            <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_@i">
                                @month
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @foreach (var date in group)
                                {
                                    var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
                                        @date.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
                                        @isoDate
                                    </label>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

What I do here is I group dates by it's month, and than I have a foreach to print out all the dates under the right month, so all the dates that belongs to may goes under the may tab, all the dates that belongs to august belongs to august.

But what I want to do is, if it only 1 month I do not want to print out a tab with the month, than I just want to print out the dates.

I were thinking to make it something like this.
If group contains more than 1 month, do that else just foreach over the dates.

Comment: How about checking with `group.length` inside `foreach`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao because group is a datetime.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah, correct but it still dosen't have .length.

Comment: Oops sorry.. Why don't you store it in a `var` before going into `foreach` like `var lists=((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.MissingDays).GroupBy(x => x.Month)` and then check `lists.Length`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I did try that, but than I can't use .GroupBy nor x.Month.

Comment: You getting any errors?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Ah, right I see the error now. Were on my part hehe, thanks that solved it.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable with your groups:

`var groups = ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.MissingDays).GroupBy(x => x.Month)`

Then you can check for its count:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="portlet-body form">
<div class="form-group">
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var group in groups)
    {
       i++;
       var month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(group.Key);
        <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                @if(groups.Count() > 1)
                {
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_@i">
                            @month
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                }
                <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @foreach (var date in group)
                            {
                                var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
                                    @date.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
                                    @isoDate
                                </label>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```